# Change CrosshairTool line style

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a crosshair set on a chart, and I would like to use a dashed line instead of the regular default line drawing. I fail to see how to go about this, and I don't understand how the `CrosshairTool` code is lowered into JavaScript, so I could customize it.

Any ideas how to get dashed crosshair lines on a Bokeh chart?